# Why does my Selenium button clicker stop working? (Python web automation)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am doing research on political giving that requires me to get data from websites like [this](https://www.fec.gov/data/disbursements/?committee_id=C00000059&two_year_transaction_period=2024&data_type=processed). I need to click the "Export" button on this site, and then click on the "Download" button that appears after "Export" is clicked. My code worked for a few times, but then stopped working randomly. I did not change the code in between use scenarios.

```
link = f'https://www.fec.gov/data/disbursements/?committee_id={committee_id}&two_year_transaction_period=2024&data_type=processed'
driver.get(link)
        
# click export button
export = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".js-export.button.button--cta.button--export")))
print(f"Found: {export.tag_name} - {export.text}")
current_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H_%M_%S", time.localtime())
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", export)
time.sleep(10)
```

Here is part of my code. This worked only a few times to click the Export button. Do websites block web automation and button clicking from Python's Selenium package?

I used my code to click the Export button a few times, and I expected it to work indefinitely. However, it stopped working after 3 attempts or so, even though I did not change any code. Also, I know that the button is being found, because my print statement prints the correct information. Basically, my programs always finds the button but does not always click it.

Comment: Many web sites don't want you doing automated scraping, and they'll throttle you if you exceed a rate limit.

Comment: But 10 second sleeps between iterations should probably be enough.